# Print only the message on warnings

Tags: python, warnings

I'm issuing lots of warnings in a validator, and I'd like to suppress everything in stdout except the message that is supplied to `warnings.warn()`.

I.e., now I see this:

```
./file.py:123: UserWarning: My looong warning message
some Python code
```

I'd like to see this:

```
My looong warning message
```

**Edit 2:** Overriding `warnings.showwarning()` turned out to work:

```
def _warning(
    message,
    category = UserWarning,
    filename = '',
    lineno = -1):
    print(message)
...
warnings.showwarning = _warning
warnings.warn('foo')
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Monkeypatch [`warnings.showwarning()`](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#warnings.showwarning) with your own custom function.

Comment: Did you read the link? And I quote: "You may replace this function with an alternative implementation by assigning to warnings.showwarning.". The manual *itself* recommends that you monkeypatch the module.

Comment: don't worry, it's perfectly normal python procedure, not drastic at all.

Answer (score 48):

There is always monkeypatching:

```
import warnings

def custom_formatwarning(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    # ignore everything except the message
    return str(msg) + '\n'

warnings.formatwarning = custom_formatwarning
warnings.warn("achtung")
```

Comment: on Python 3.6 I get TypeError: custom_formatwarning() got an unexpected keyword argument 'line'. So I changed function signature to: `def custom_formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line='')`

Comment: I had the "same got an unexpected keyword argument 'line'" in Python 3.6, but I just changed the signature to `def custom_formatwarning(msg, *a, **b):` so it also catches keyword args.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but, you can also do this with a lambda instead of a function:
`warnings.formatwarning = lambda msg, *args, **kwargs: f'{msg}\n'`

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, not the other one

Comment: How do I get the warning type like `DeprecationWarning`? I tried `category` but it contains nothing

Comment: This works, although I found `mypy` complained about it.  If I'm reading the Python docs correctly, we should instead override `showwarning()`.  Doing this and using the explicit signature made `mypy` happy. https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.showwarning

Answer (score 13):

Use the [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) instead of `warnings`.

Comment: This is what I have ended up with in the vast majority of situations where I originally tried to use `warnings`. If you are struggling with `warnings`, you should consider this option. Seriously.

Comment: there's some subtlety in choosing warnings over logging.warn https://stackoverflow.com/a/14762106/5335565

Answer (score 11):

Here's what I'm doing to omit *just* the source code line.  This is by and large as suggested by the documentation, but it was a bit of a struggle to figure out what exactly to change. (In particular, I tried in various ways to keep the source line out of `showwarnings` but couldn't get it to work the way I wanted.)

```
# Force warnings.warn() to omit the source code line in the message
formatwarning_orig = warnings.formatwarning
warnings.formatwarning = lambda message, category, filename, lineno, line=None: \
    formatwarning_orig(message, category, filename, lineno, line='')
```

Just passing `line=None` would cause Python to use `filename` and `lineno` to figure out a value for `line` automagically, but passing an empty string instead fixes that.

Comment: I know this is super old but I've done a similar thing and that also worked. However if I do this inside a function, the warning behavior changes on the global scope. Every warning comes after calling that function adopts the modified behavior. Do you know a way to limit its effect?

Comment: Hmm, I only ever used this in global context. As a freak workaround, you could define a global variable which is used inside the `lambda` to decide whether or not the `line` value is overridden or not. (At that point, maybe use a named function rather than a `lambda`?)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't matter where I did these things. I also tried the original defeinition saving and restoring but no avail yet.

Comment: Nevermind this is a known issue apparently https://bugs.python.org/issue18081#msg191342. It is indeed annoying

Answer (score 0):

You have stated that you don't like the default message:

```
./file.py:123: UserWarning: My looong warning message
some Python code
```

You said that you would like to see only:

```
My looong warning message
```

But I am willing to guess that the core issues here are the file path and the source code being displayed. These can be removed more simply by passing an additional argument:

```
warnings.warn(msg, stacklevel=3)
```

This will produce a message that looks like:

```
sys:1: UserWarning: 
Your long message
```