# warnings.warn() vs. logging.warning()

Tags: python, logging, warnings, python-logging

What is the difference between [`warnings.warn()`](https://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn) and [`logging.warn()`](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.warning) in terms of what they do and how they should be used?

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15655674/4742780): "logging.warn has been deprecated since Python 3.3 and you should use logging.warning."

Answer (score 153):

I agree with the other answer -- `logging` is for logging and `warning` is for warning -- but I'd like to add more detail.

Here is a tutorial-style HOWTO taking you through the steps in using the `logging` module. 
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

It directly answers your question:

> warnings.warn() in library code if the issue is avoidable and the
>   client application should be modified to eliminate the warning
>
> logging.warning() if there is nothing the client application can do
>   about the situation, but the event should still be noted

Answer (score 108):

[`logging.warning`](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.warning) just logs something at the `WARNING` level, in the same way that `logging.info` logs at the `INFO` level and `logging.error` logs at the `ERROR` level. It has no special behaviour.

[`warnings.warn`](https://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn) emits a [`Warning`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#Warning), which may be printed to `stderr`, ignored completely, or thrown like a normal `Exception` (potentially crashing your application) depending upon the precise `Warning` subclass emitted and how you've configured your *Warnings Filter*. By default, warnings will be printed to `stderr` or ignored.

Warnings emitted by `warnings.warn` are often useful to know about, but easy to miss (especially if you're running a Python program in a background process and not capturing `stderr`). For that reason, it can be helpful to have them logged.

Python provides a built-in integration between the `logging` module and the `warnings` module to let you do this; just call [`logging.captureWarnings(True)`](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.captureWarnings) at the start of your script and all warnings emitted by the `warnings` module will automatically be logged at level `WARNING`.

Answer (score 49):

Besides the [canonical explanation in official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#when-to-use-logging)

> warnings.warn() in library code if the issue is avoidable and the client application should be modified to eliminate the warning
>
> logging.warning() if there is nothing the client application can do about the situation, but the event should still be noted

It is also worth noting that, by default `warnings.warn("same message")` will show up only once. That is a major noticeable difference. Quoted from [official doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html)

> Repetitions of a particular warning for the same source location are typically suppressed.

```
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.warn("foo")
__main__:1: UserWarning: foo
>>> warnings.warn("foo")
>>> warnings.warn("foo")
>>>
>>> import logging
>>> logging.warn("bar")
WARNING:root:bar
>>> logging.warn("bar")
WARNING:root:bar
>>> logging.warn("bar")
WARNING:root:bar
>>>
>>>
>>> warnings.warn("fur")
__main__:1: UserWarning: fur
>>> warnings.warn("fur")
>>> warnings.warn("fur")
>>>
```

Comment: Note that "show up only once" is the intended default behaviour, but warning filters can change this.

Comment: the answer clearly says this is the default behavior