# What's the difference between logging.warn and logging.warning in Python?

Tags: python, logging, warnings, python-logging

The samples at http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html use both `warn` and `warning`.

Comment: Not the same question, but some Googlers may have been looking for: [Python warnings.warn() vs. logging.warning()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595009/python-warnings-warn-vs-logging-warning)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [warnings.warn() vs. logging.warning()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9595009/6862601).

Answer (score 159, accepted):

`logging.warn` has been deprecated since Python 3.3 and you should use `logging.warning`.

Prior to Python 3.3, `logging.warn` and `logging.warning` were the same function, but `logging.warn` was not documented, as noted in a closed issue in the Python bug tracker http://bugs.python.org/issue13235:

> That's deliberate. The original code (before incorporation into Python) had warn(), which was kept for backward compatibility. The docs refer to warning() because that's what everyone is supposed to use. The method names map to the lower case of the appropriate logging level name.

`logging.warn()` was kept for backwards compatibility but [a deprecation warning was added](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.3/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1252-L1253). `logging.warning()` is what everyone is supposed to use.

Answer (score 44):

Prior to Python 3.3, they are the same, however `warn` is deprecated:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.warn is logging.warning
True
```

Comment: Beware, nowadays the same comparison returns `False`.