# need to see the descriptions of logging output of various modules in python

Tags: python, logging

I want to create a log file in addition to standard output. I am using the inbuilt module such as:

```
def dedup_col_col2(final_recos):
    """
    Removing duplicate combination of col1-col2 for any single Muid
    """
    recommendation_log()
    def f(data,col1, col2):
        ra=data[~(data[[col1,col2]].duplicated())]
        return ra
    .....Do something(carry on)

def function_logger(file_level, console_level = None):
    """
    Logging function to log all the warning/error messages
    It writes both to console and log file
    """
    function_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    logger = logging.getLogger(function_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) #By default, logs all messages
    if console_level != None:
        ch = logging.StreamHandler() #StreamHandler logs to console
        ch.setLevel(console_level)
        ch_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
        ch.setFormatter(ch_format)
        logger.addHandler(ch)
    fh = logging.FileHandler("{0}.log".format(function_name))
    fh.setLevel(file_level)
    fh_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(lineno)d - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(fh_format)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    return logger

def recommendation_log():
    recommendation_log_logger = function_logger(logging.DEBUG, logging.DEBUG)
    recommendation_log_logger.debug('debug message')
    recommendation_log_logger.info('info message')
    recommendation_log_logger.warn('warn message')
    recommendation_log_logger.error('error message')
    recommendation_log_logger.critical('critical message')    
def main():
    recommendation_log()  
    final_recos1=dedup_tbid_tbidrank(final_recos)
    logging.shutdown()
```

Code is taken from the following link:
[How do I write log messages to a log file and the console at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574257/how-do-i-write-log-messages-to-a-log-file-and-the-console-at-the-same-time)

Now when I execute it code it shows various debug-error messages on console. When I open the log file, it shows me following output in the recommendation_log.log file:

```
2015-07-07 12:19:16,392 - 339 - DEBUG    - debug message
2015-07-07 12:19:16,392 - 340 - INFO     - info message
2015-07-07 12:19:16,393 - 341 - WARNING  - warn message
2015-07-07 12:19:16,393 - 342 - ERROR    - error message
2015-07-07 12:19:16,393 - 343 - CRITICAL - critical message
2015-07-07 12:22:03,176 - 339 - DEBUG    - debug message
2015-07-07 12:22:03,176 - 339 - DEBUG    - debug message
```

Now I want to understand that what is the source of these errors and I want to see the descriptions of these messages, in the same way as they are shown on the console.

EDIT: On console it displays me warnings such as:

```
***Cmeans_omni.py:37: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df['CampaignName_upd'] = df['CampaignName']
/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py:1170: DtypeWarning: Columns (3,7) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  data = self._reader.read(nrows)***
```

**Now I want to understand that what is the source of these errors and I also want to see the descriptions of these messages in the log file, in the same way as they are shown on the console**.

Basically I want to see the description, as stated above in the log file and actual line no , from where it is originating. The line number, shown in sample output is not the actual line number, it is the line number of the line corresponding to error in function.

I have been reading about the logging module a day long, but cannot figure out the solution.

Comment: _it shows various debug-error messages on console_, [...] _I want to see these messages as they are shown on the console_ - what exactly do you see where and what do you expect to see? Please help me helping you!

Comment: @Finwood Thanks for responding!!. I have edited my question, explaining what exactly I want by giving you the sample output on console.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two things.

Let's first concentrate on the logging. Your approach seems to work, but looks quite messy. This is the same idea, but with less overhead:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

fmt = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - "
                        "%(module)s:%(lineno)s - "
                        "%(levelname)s: %(message)s")

# Loggers need handlers for handling log messages.
# Lets's add a StreamHandler for console output...
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.setFormatter(fmt)
sh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(sh)

# ...and a FileHandler for Logfile writing:
fh = logging.FileHandler('log.file', 'a')
fh.setFormatter(fmt)
fh.setLevel(logging.WARN)
logger.addHandler(fh)

# Now let's log some stuff:
logger.debug("Foobar")
logger.info("Meh")
logger.warn("I warned you.")
logger.error("This might be an error.")
```

If you encounter errors and want to include the traceback in your log, use [`logger.exception()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception):

```
try:
    x = 1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    # this includes the traceback as level ERROR
    logger.exception(e)
```

However, your `Error` is just a `Warning`, which does not force the program to terminate. If you need to do some warning-related stuff, you might want to take a look at the [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) module.

In this case, `pandas` throws a `SettingWithCopyWarning`, you are assigning values to a *copy* of a part of your DataFrame. This means, everything you modify will not affect your original data, since you are working with the copy only. Use `df.loc[]` [as explained in the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) to get past this.

---

#### Update:

Using [`warnings.warn()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn) messages, you could add them to your logger using the [`catch_warnings()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings)-contextmanager:

```
import warnings

class WarningsAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    """Copy `warnings.WarningMessage` information to log record"""
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        if isinstance(msg, warnings.WarningMessage):
            msg = "%s: %s" % (msg.category.__name__, msg.message)
        return msg, kwargs

adapter = WarningsAdapter(logger, extra=None)

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as warning_list:
    # do something throwing a warning
    warnings.warn("This is a warning message.", RuntimeWarning)
    warnings.warn("Something might have gone wrong.", UserWarning)
    # something else
    for w in warning_list:
        adapter.warning(w)
```

You might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9595009/1525423) though, the use cases of `warnings.warn()` and `logging.warning()` are being discussed there.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response!! Actually warnings do not have an impact on my output. But I want this SettingWithCopyWarning to be placed in a Log file. Basically I want to store to any warning/error in a log File. I think for warnings storage, I have to use warning.showwarning() function as stated in the warning module.

Comment: @finwood.....the last line is throwing me error...'WarningsAdapter' object has no attribute 'warn'...any idea?

Comment: What Python version are you using? Try using `adapter.warning(w)`

Comment: I am using Anaconda Python 2.7+. I am using adapter.warning(w) only as indicated in the code above.

Comment: Is `adapter.warning(w)` instead of `adapter.warn(w)` working?

Comment: Apology did not noticed your recent edit...yes adapter.warning(w) seems to work!!!.....so similar to warning we can store any debug/error message?

Comment: This van be done by updating the Logging level of your FileHandler, changing `fh.setLevel(logging.WARN)
` to `logging.DEBUG`. Make sure you've understood the [Python `logging` module](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83546/discussion-between-user2007506-and-finwood).

Comment: Hi!!...I have posted a message in chat room...please have a look at it

Comment: @Finwood...chatroom page expired..so I am pasting here...so basically what I intend...in very simple context is that...for example I want that setcopy warning message as explained in the above example to be stored in the log.file along with the line number...with the present code I can know the type of error(debug, warning or critical) but I want to see the exact description in the log file!!!