# Python warnings- how to not print the source line?

Tags: python, warnings

When I issue a warnings.warn() warning in python, the output to stderr includes not just my warning method, but also the offending line from the source code. I would like to suppress this line from the source code, as it really detracts from expressing the warning clearly. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Take a look at warning filters - https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter

Comment: See e.g. [Python: Print only the message on warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187269/python-print-only-the-message-on-warnings)

Comment: 2022 update: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26433913/5122790 for a solution that doesn't require hacky monkey-patching

Answer (score 3):

You can monkey-patch the [formatwarning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.formatwarning) function.  If you look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/warnings.py#l37), it shouldn't be too hard to write a replacement that doesn't have a line number there.

Comment: What do you mean by `monkey-patch`?

Comment: Monkey-patch just means modifying a function or object without changing its source.