# Make Python's `warnings.warn()` not mention itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings

My minimum example is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import warnings

warnings.warn('Run Forest run!', stacklevel=2)
warnings.warn('Run Forest run!')
```

and it will output

```
sys:1: UserWarning: Run Forest run!
./file.py:6: UserWarning: Run Forest run!
  warnings.warn('Run Forest run!')
```

The first line gives me to little info. The second line is perfect, giving me source file and line number ... but I'd like to get rid of the redundant third line. Is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print only the message on warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187269/print-only-the-message-on-warnings)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out it is possible to let `warnings.warn()` collect all the info and just costumize the way the info is printed:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import warnings

def warning_on_one_line(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None):
    return '%s:%s: %s: %s\n' % (filename, lineno, category.__name__, message)

warnings.formatwarning = warning_on_one_line

warnings.warn('Run Forest run!', stacklevel=2)
warnings.warn('Run Forest run!')
```

Output:

```
sys:1: UserWarning: Run Forest run!
./file.py:15: UserWarning: Run Forest run!
```

**Source:** [Python module of the week](http://pymotw.com/2/warnings/)

Comment: Nice solution. Not sure if `file` in the function signature is due to an older version of python but the [current documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.formatwarning) shows `formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line=None)`.

Answer (score 6):

The reason you are getting the "redundant" line is because if you don't provide the `stacklevel` parameter the default `stacklevel` is 1, which is basically telling the user the exact line of code that the warning originated from, which is your warning function call `warnings.warn('Run Forest Run!')`.

If you're not happy with the way it functions, you can use the `warnings.warn_explicit()` function to customise it.

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/warnings.html#available-functions

Answer (score 2):

In case you're trying to catch exception/error, and want to see both your custom warning message and traceback, you might prefer to use traceback.print_exc() :

```
import traceback
import warnings

def _formatwarning(msg, *a):
   try:
       traceback.print_exc()
   except:
       pass
   return str(msg)

warnings.formatwarning = _formatwarning
```

which will make warn("your message") print traceback without mention the call to warn() itself.

**UPDATE:** on Python 3.6 you need to change function signature to:

```
def _formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line='')
```