# Moving only Files in Directories

Tags: python-2.7, directory, shutil

I have looked extensively on this site and I can't see an example that fits the bill. I have 4 directories each of which contains a number of files and another directory called 'Superseded'. I am trying to write a script that will move all files in each folder into the 'Superseded' folder but I'm not having any luck.

```
import os, shutil
source = r'U:\Data\All\Python_Test\Exports\GLA'
dest = r'U:\Data\All\Python_Test\Exports\Superseded'
listofFiles = os.listdir(source)
 for f in listofFiles:
    fullPath = source + "/" + f
    shutil.move(fullPath, dest)
```

I can only get this to work for one directory and even then only when I've made the destination directory outside of the GLA directory if that makes sense.

I know there is a a os.path.isfile() module so that I can only move the files but I can't seem to get it to work. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: are the 4 in the same folder or do you give the 4 paths manually?

Comment: The 4 directories are in the same folder, it's U:\Data\All\Python_Test\Exports and it contains the four directories, each of which contains a 'Superseded' folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import os

#from:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158076/implement-touch-using-python
# I use this to create some empty file to move around later
def touch(fname, times=None):
    fhandle = open(fname, 'a')
    try:
        os.utime(fname, times)
    finally:
        fhandle.close()


# this function is only to create the folders and files to be moved        
def create_files_in_known_folders():
    nameList=["source_dir_{:02d}".format(x) for x in range(4)]
    for name in nameList:
        path=os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~",name))
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.mkdir(path)
        ssPath=os.path.join(path,"superseded")  
        if not os.path.exists(ssPath):
            os.mkdir(ssPath)  
        for i in range(3):
            filename="{}_{:02d}.dat".format(name,i)
            filepath=os.path.join(path, filename)
            if not os.path.exists(filepath):
                touch(filepath)

# THIS is actually the function doing what the OP asked for
# there many details that can be tweaked
def move_from_known_to_dest():
    # here my given names from above
    nameList=["source_dir_{:02d}".format(x) for x in range(4)]
    # and my destination path
    destPath=os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~","dest"))
    # not interested in files that are in subfolders
    # if those would exist change to os.walk and 
    # exclude the destination folder with according if...:
    for name in nameList:
        path=os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~",name))
        dirList=os.listdir(path)
        print path
        for fileName in dirList:
            filePath=os.path.join(path, fileName)
            print filePath
            if os.path.isfile(filePath):
                destPath=os.path.join(path,"superseded",fileName)
                print destPath
                #alternatively you can chose to 1) overwrite ()might not work 2)delete first 3) not copy
                # another option is to check for existence and if 
                # present add a number to the dest-file-name
                # use while loop to check for first non-present number 
                assert not os.path.exists(destPath), "file {} already exits".format(destPath)
                #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python
                os.rename( filePath, destPath)



if __name__=="__main__":
    create_files_in_known_folders()
    #break here and check that filestructure and files have been created
    move_from_known_to_dest()
```

But, think carefully what to do if the file already exits in your destination folder. 
`os.walk` might also be something you want to look at.

Implementing several options for the copy behaviour may look like this:

```
import warnings

#from:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187269/python-print-only-the-message-on-warnings
formatwarning_orig = warnings.formatwarning
warnings.formatwarning = lambda message, category, filename, lineno, line=None: \
    formatwarning_orig(message, category, filename, lineno, line='')


def move_from_known_to_dest_extra(behaviour='overwrite'):
    assert behaviour in ['overwrite','leave','accumulate'], "unknown behaviour: {}".format(behaviour)
    nameList=["source_dir_{:02d}".format(x) for x in range(4)]
    destPath=os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~","dest"))
    for name in nameList:
        path=os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~",name))
        dirList=os.listdir(path)
        for fileName in dirList:
            filePath=os.path.join(path, fileName)
            if os.path.isfile(filePath):
                destPath=os.path.join(path,"superseded",fileName)
                # simplest case...does not exist so copy
                if not os.path.exists(destPath):
                    os.rename( filePath, destPath)
                else:
                    if behaviour=='leave':
                        warnings.warn( "Warning! Not copying file: {}; file {} already exists!".format(filePath, destPath))
                    elif behaviour =='overwrite':
                        os.remove(destPath)
                        # documentation states:
                        # On Windows, if dst already exists, OSError will be raised even if it is a file.
                        os.rename( filePath, destPath)
                        warnings.warn( "Warning!Overwriting file: {}.".format(destPath))
                    elif behaviour=='accumulate': #redundant but OK
                        addPost=0
                        while True:
                            newDestPath=destPath+"{:04d}".format(addPost)
                            if not os.path.exists(newDestPath):
                                break
                            addPost+=1
                            assert addPost < 10000, "Clean up the mess!"
                        os.rename( filePath, newDestPath)
                    else:
                        assert 0, "Unknown copy behaviour requested."
```

Additionally one might check for file permissions as, e.g., `os.remove()` may raise an exception. In this case, however, I assume that permissions are properly set by the OP.

Comment: Thanks. Would you know How I could change this nameList=["U:/Data/All/PAR_Exports/{:02d}".format(x) for x in range(4)] so that it can be four folders based on characters?

Comment: @Dunuts Hi, you have at least two possibilities here: 1) `nameList=["U:/Data/All/PAR_Exports/{}".format(x) for x in ['a','b','c','d']]`  or in case of abcd 2) `nameList=["U:/Data/All/PAR_Exports/{}".format(chr(97+x)) for x in range(4)] ` chose different offset functions for other characters. And a tip at the end. To avoid confusion in paths with `\ ` or `/` use `os.path.join()`.